# How to configure data in DataGridView (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have DataGridView which as for DataSource a list of Device. A Device has a Category and I'd like to know how to display in the DataGridView the Properties of the Category (for the moment it uses ToString() to display it).

```
public class Device
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Category {get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
}
```

In my Form :

```
List<Device> devices = (...); //load my devices
myDataGridView.DataSource = devices;
```

So in my DataGridView it will display Category.ToString() but I'd like it to display separately the Category's Properties.

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand you just need to bind the right property into the XAML.
For a simple exemple, if the list is defined as DataSource :

```xml
<DataGrid Name="yourName" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Device ID " Binding="{Binding Id}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Device Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category ID" Binding="{Binding Category.Id}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category Name" Binding="{Binding Category.Name}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Hope it'll help you !

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you just made. I don't have any XAML in my project. And it is a DataGridView I'm working with.

Comment: How do you display your data then ? so i'll try to find another solution

Comment: I just set the myDataGridView.DataSource property and it does all the work by itself.

Comment: Actually you need to generate your column by yourself, that's why the AutoGenerateColumn is disabled in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `DataGridView` isn’t going to know what to do with a “Class” in a “Class.”  The same idea is applied if there was a ‘List` as a property of the “Device” Class. The grid is going to interpret the Class/List as “Multiple” objects and it isn’t going to “parse” out those objects into individual columns. Possibly a third party grid may do this.

I will not argue that if the Class has nothing but single non-collection type objects that it would do this simple parsing… unfortunately the out of the box `DataGridView` won’t do this for you. Your code is going to have to “flatted” the data to get it all displayed into the grid.

As you commented, a simple fix is to override the Category’s `ToString` method to return a string with “both” values concatenated. This will return the data, but as you noted, “both” values are going to be in a “single” column.

```
public class Category {

  public int Id { get; }
  public string Name { get; }

  public Category(int id, string name) {
    Id = id;
    Name = name;
  }

  public override string ToString() {
    return Id + ", " + Name;
  }
}
```

Given this, I would guess that it may be easier to write a method to “flatten” the data and return a `DataTable` with all fields. However, given that there are only two (2) fields, it is possible for the `Device` Class to also have the `Category` properties. Example, if you make the `Device` Class’s `Category` property `private` then expose the `Cataegory`’s two properties in the `Device` Class. Something like….

```
class Device {

  public int Id { get; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  private Category _Category { get; set; }

  public Device(int id, string name, Category category) {
    Id = id;
    Name = name;
    _Category = category;
  }

  public int CatID {
    get {
      return _Category.Id;
    }
  }

  public string CatName {
    get {
      return _Category.Name;
    }
  }
}
```

I am betting a dedicated method to “flatten” the data and return a `DataTable` would be a better approach, however as mentioned, since there are only two fields, the above solution should work.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to find something about this `DataTable` you talk about